# How to redirect pages in a user control?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-controls

Can someone tell me how to add several pages in a user control `.ascx`, I need to redirect from a page to another.

How to do that?

Should I add `page.aspx` to the user control?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in two ways

1. Using server-side use `Response.Redirect(URL)`
2. Using client-side use `window.location.href = url;`

You can't add a Page inside UserControl. User Control basically lives inside a Page.

Comment: Yes User Control is inside a Client Web Part,can I call more than a user Control in my web part ?? How do I realize more than an interface page ? My question is not about how to redirect from page to another but how can I proceed ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try adding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I called a User Control from my web part and then I retrieved data  from  SP lists using CSOM. Then this page ( In which data is retrieved ) should be redirected to a second  page ( when a user clicked in a button he should be redirected to a second page). So should I  prepare the second page in other user control ? Or in the same user control  in which I retrieve data?

Comment: It depends on how complex your WebPart is. There is no problem with adding multiple user controls in same webpart (you can show/hide instead of redirecting). Or you can create a different web part, then add the user control inside it.. Then create a page and host it.. Then redirect to new page.